# Can I pass an object as an argument to a widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a template widget that creates buttons and a family members class, can I pass an object of said class as an argument to the template so that the button says the name of that family member, for example?

```
class Template extends StatelessWidget {


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 70,
        width: 120,
        child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){print('hey');},
                  child: Text(members.name,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify)
              ),
```

The rest of the template doesn't matter so I cut it off

Comment: You can. Pass it to the `Template`'s constructor and add it as a variable in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can,

```
class Template extends StatelessWidget {

Family members;
Template(this.members);

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 70,
        width: 120,
        child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){print('hey');},
                  child: Text(members.name,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify)
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like a regular object just declare your variable and reference it in the constructor and you're good to go

```
 class Template extends StatelessWidget {
    final members;

    Template(this.members) : super();

      ...

   }
```